# Structural stability of Arnold's Cat Map

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, automorphism-group, stability-theory

In Wikipedia it says that "hyperbolic automorphisms of the torus, such as the Arnold's cat map, are structurally stable", so I am trying to understand why this is true. What $C^1$-small perturbation should I use to prove this?

Answer (score 0):

The map is an Anosov diffeomorphism and hyperbolicity is a stable property. This needs some knowledge about hyperbolic dynamical systems.

I recommend you to read "Introduction to the Modern Theory of Dynamical Systems" by Anatole Katok and Boris Hasselblatt, your could see the map is a Anosov diffeomorphism by the definition of Anosov diffeomorphism at page 263, then the Corollary 18.2.2: Anosov diffeomorphisms are structurally stable, shows the map is structurally stable.

The most important thing is the map does not contain eigenvalues with absolute value 1, this is where hyperbolicity comes from.